# How to change the editing style of UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

From the below picture, I want to change the color of multiple selection buttons and the background color while selected(the blue part).

The editingStyle is defined below

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete|UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
}
```

I tried to set tintColor of the tableView,the color of multiple selection buttons changed but the background color doesn't change.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? and where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `tintColor` and `multipleSelectionBackgroundView` for each cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //...

    cell.tintColor = UIColor.orange

    let bgview = UIView()
    bgview.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    cell.multipleSelectionBackgroundView = bgview

    //...
}
```

[image: sample]